# How to setup bolt CMS with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, bolt-cms

I am using Bolt CMS and basically the database config file is a YML file that looks like below:

```
# Database setup. The driver can be either 'sqlite', 'mysql' or 'postgres'.
#
# For SQLite, only the databasename is required. However, MySQL and PostgreSQL
# also require 'username', 'password', and optionally 'host' ( and 'port' ) if the database
# server is not on the same host as the web server.
#
# If you're trying out Bolt, just keep it set to SQLite for now.
database:
    driver: mysqli
    databasename: bolt
```

If I keep these settings and navigate to http://localhost:8080/bolt/public/, I can see the login screen, but I want to be using MySQL and so I change the settings to the following:

```
# Database setup. The driver can be either 'sqlite', 'mysql' or 'postgres'.
#
# For SQLite, only the databasename is required. However, MySQL and PostgreSQL
# also require 'username', 'password', and optionally 'host' ( and 'port' ) if the database
# server is not on the same host as the web server.
#
# If you're trying out Bolt, just keep it set to SQLite for now.
database:
    driver: MySQL
    databasename: bolt
    host: localhost
    username: root
    password:
```

Now I get the following screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T42el.jpg

I'll paste the error below too:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Bolt\Exception\LowLevelDatabaseException' with message 'MySQL was selected as the database type, but it is not supported.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bolt\vendor\bolt\bolt\src\Exception\LowLevelDatabaseException.php:41 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bolt\vendor\bolt\bolt\src\Configuration\LowlevelChecks.php(188): Bolt\Exception\LowLevelDatabaseException::unsupportedDriver('MySQL') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\bolt\vendor\bolt\bolt\src\Configuration\ResourceManager.php(451): Bolt\Configuration\LowlevelChecks->doDatabaseCheck() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\bolt\vendor\bolt\bolt\src\Configuration\ResourceManager.php(412): Bolt\Configuration\ResourceManager->verifyDb() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\bolt\vendor\bolt\bolt\src\Configuration\ResourceManager.php(395): Bolt\Configuration\ResourceManager->postInitialize() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\bolt\vendor\bolt\bolt\src\Application.php(59): Bolt\Configuration\ResourceManager->initialize() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\bolt\vendor\bolt\bolt\app\bootstrap.php(123): Bolt\Application->__construct(Array) #6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\bolt\vendor\bolt\bolt\src\Exception\LowLevelDatabaseException.php on line 41
```

Any idea how I can get MySQL working with Bolt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your driver name is incorrect.

Use `driver: mysql`